# vbLeftJustify what is the .net version?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I have an old VB6 Project that I am trying to convert to .NET. In the project vbLeftJustify was used. What is the .NET version of vbLeftJustify?

```
.set_ColAlignment(j, vbLeftJustify)
```

Comment: Pray tell, what's on the left of that?  Quacks like a grid control, vbLeftJustify was only accidentally correct.  It is 0 so it is not a great accident.

Comment: Could you let us know what kind of control you are using? Most of the controls default to Left Align.

Comment: @alstonp it is a flex grid, "MSFlexGrid"

Comment: @alstonp I wasn't sure if I had to change to DataGridView yet. The MSFlexGrid controls seem to be working so far, besides the issue that I am having with the vbLeftJustify

Comment: @nate You don't have to migrate to a DataGridView, just be aware you are using a legacy control which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Reivised as @Hans Passant pointed out:

You are confusing `vbLeftJustify` with `flexAlignLeftTop`

If you are using an MSFlexGrid pass the value "0" for the `flexAlignLeftTop` as per here:
[ColAlignment, ColAlignmentBand, ColAlignmentHeader Properties (MSHFlexGrid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239893%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

If you are using a DataGridView:

There is no `vbLeftJustify` in vb.net in order to align the DataGrid properly you will need to set the `DefaultCellStyle` of the Column header like so:

```
Dim DataGridViewCellStyle1 As DataGridViewCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle()

DataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
Me.Column1.DefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle1
```

Answer (score 1):

> it is a flex grid, "MSFlexGrid"

You are supposed to use *flexAlignLeft*.  Column alignment doesn't have anything to do with justification, just alignment.  Its value is 0 as well so this worked correctly by accident.

This got notably fixed, you can't make this mistake anymore in VB.NET.  Enum values now have associated type, it is not just a constant anymore.

Getting your project migrated to VB.NET is certainly easier when you keep the old VB6 controls.  Do beware the deployment headaches, you still need to get that OCX installed on your user's machine.  Moving to DataGridView is your long-term solution.

Comment: +1. Do you need `Option Strict On` for the VB.Net compiler to warn you if you accidentally misuse enum values in this way? I can't remember.